# Sferik/t (Twitter) - On Ruby 2.7.0 (Incompatible library)

Tags: ruby, macos, oauth, openssl, rubygems

ok so I am new to ruby (Just experimenting, I'm a Javascript person) But I have been playing with the Twitter or (t) ruby gem by Sferik (Github Source below) and kept running into mainly Ruby compatibility issues. This CLI script states that it was tested for Ruby 2.4 - 2.7. The first issue was that I'm using a make and the script required 2.4.x or greater so I got ruby 2.7.0 working fine on macOS, rebuilt ruby, rebuilt gems, etc. Now that I have ruby upgraded and gems working again, the specific command I am trying to get to work is:

```
$ sudo t leaders | xargs t unfollow
```

Github Source Link: https://github.com/sferik/t

And the output I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    21: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    20: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    19: from /Users/usert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/t:23:in `<main>'
    18: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/t:23:in `load'
    17: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/t-3.1.0/bin/t:7:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    15: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    14: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/oauth-0.5.4/lib/oauth.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    12: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    11: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/oauth-0.5.4/lib/oauth/client/helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     9: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     8: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/oauth-0.5.4/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     6: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     5: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/https.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     3: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     2: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/openssl-2.2.0/lib/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/openssl-2.2.0/lib/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
```

It looks like the OpenSSL lib is not compatible. I am not used to debugging Ruby so I'm looking for help on figuring out what library to try to fix, or if I should simply try downgrading Ruby version.

Comment: Have you tried removing the gems and reset brew ? `rm -rf /Users/user/.gem; brew update-reset.`

Comment: i tried that, now i have a new warning.

Comment: `/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/psych-3.2.0/lib/psych.rb:575:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/user/.trc (Errno::EACCES)`

Comment: Try changing permission of the file at /Users/user/.trc